# Can you make a value stick throughout multiple solutions?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, variables

I'm going to do my best to describe my current situation, so bear with me.

In my application, there's many solutions that reference the same class to grab information from the database. They all use the same call to the class throughout the multiple solutions, is there any way I could have that value that it's checking for in the multiple solutions stick and only get called once in the class and have all solutions use the value instead of calling the class and running through the logic to find the value?

I just feel there's a lot of wasted time having to call the same class to get the same value that hasn't changed over and over again and is only getting re-run to get the value because different solutions are calling it. I'm not sure what to even look up to try to research this on what I could do to keep the value available throughout all solutions accessing it.

If you understood my problem, please provide some insight, or if it made no sense I'll try to re-clarify.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Please give some code.

Comment: You can put an application setting in the machine.config file on your system, all projects will have access to the value.

Comment: Sounds like you're talking about caching. Would this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323523/c-sharp-implementing-a-application-wide-cache

Comment: By multiple solutions, do you mean multiple processes? It that case the application-wide cache suggested by @Nick won't help.